# Map a structure across files

Tags: c++

I have a TCP header file in its library where some structures are defined - like for SNMP

```
stuct objectId {..id[MAXLEN]; ..}
struct SnmpTypes {.. uint32 ForwardIp; ..}
```

Now there structures contain elements and variables in it. I need to access them in our application code. Since the above two types are in TCP stack probably users will not know the elements inside them. In my code I include then by external declaration.

To provide a user interface how should we declare or include the above mentioned structures in application code. if I create a same types of structures in my application I would be duplicating or rather later may miss some TCP stack updates - but the how would the user know the variables?

Comment: If it is about how to expose a translation unit's types, functions, and probably variables to  other translation units, have you considered providing header files?

Comment: The declaration are already defined in say snmp.h or some other file in TCP library - yes in user application side I want the unit's types, functions, and probably variables be viewable / available in simpler format - which header files are you stating - exposing, is it snmp.h of TCP library will create more confusion - but at the same time I do want duplication